# PHP Checking Filesize to see if its changing

Tags: php, while-loop, filesize

I have a web page that calls an external process. This process writes a text file in to a folder on my server. I have no control over this external process.

I'm trying to monitor the file to see if it's file size changes, which it will while it's being written to. Once the external process has stopped writing to it the filesize will remain the same.

I thought something like this may work:

```
<?php

$old = 0;
$new = 1;

while ($old == $new) {
    $old = filesize ('/http/test/test.txt');
    echo $old;
    sleep(2);
    $new = filesize ('/http/test/test.txt');
    echo $new;
}
echo $old;
echo $new;
echo "done";
?>
```

But it doesn't. How do I pause my script until the file has stopped increasing in size ?

There are similar questions on here, but I've not seen an example of doing this with out using `flock()` or `lsof` both of which I don't have access to.

Can this be done ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
this seems to be working.

```
<?php

$old = 0; $new = 1;
$filePath = "/http/test/test.txt";

while ($old != $new) {
    $old = filesize ($filePath);
    clearstatcache();
    sleep(1);
    $new = filesize ($filePath);
    clearstatcache();
}
echo "done";
?>
```

Comment: Your while loop will never execute as old != new when it first initiates!

Comment: Thanks. Changing `==` to `!=` does seem to work better but the php page finishes before the file has finished being written to. Any ideas ?

Comment: set_time_limit(120); at the top of the page will allow it to run for 120 seconds.  How long will it typically need to execute for?

Comment: The docs say that that IGNORES sleep time though, so it shouldn't need to be set too high in theory! http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: All file operations are cached as PHP was not designed for this kind of operations, and is optimized for short burst performance. See the answer below as it solves your problem.

Answer (score 6):

You need to call clearstatcache() on the loop.

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

> Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache()
>   for more details.

An example implementation (Here I use modification time to check changes, but you can use filesize instead):

```
$filePath = '/http/test/test.txt';
$timeInSeconds = 2;

if (file_exists($filePath)) {

  $fileModificationUnixTime = filemtime($filePath);

  while (filemtime($filePath) === $fileModificationUnixTime) {
    echo 'No changes found.';
    sleep($timeInSeconds);
    clearstatcache(); // clears the cached result
  }

  echo 'Changes found';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tested this and it returns to screen with `No changes found. Changes found` before the file has finished being created. I've testing the file creation using bash and `yes "HelloWorld" | head -n 5000000 > test.txt`

Comment: Just added an update to my original post. That seems to work.